# How can I use Struts iteration variable inside c:set?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, el

How can I use struts iteration variable inside `c:set`? 
Can we set variable `dat` like below?

```
   <s:iterator value="userResultHistory" var="result" status="status">
   ...
   <c:set var="dat" value="%{result.date}"/>

   <% 
    String result;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMM yy");
    result = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("dat");
    System.out.println("result" + result);
   %>

   <td><%=result%></td>
   ...

   </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<c:set var="dat" value="${result.date}"/>
```

The value stack is available to EL in Struts2 due to its request wrapper.